# Enum.values() not working in GWT throws compilation error

Tags: gwt, enums, gxt

I'm using an enum class in my GWT class.I'm using enum.values() in order to iterate through the enum class. this throws error during complilation. the GXT version i'm using is 2.2.5. gwt-dev jar version is 2.4.0

Tried using EnumSet.allOf(DaysOfWeekEnum.class) still getting same error

This article -> https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/7065 says that it was a bug with gxt. but could not find a fix from it

```
    for (DaysOfWeekEnum day : DaysOfWeekEnum.values()) { 
        System.out.println(day); 
    }
```

Getting the below exception:

```
 [java] Apr 23, 2019 5:27:38 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
 [java] WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
 [java] Compiling module com.dashboard_gxt
 [java]    Validating newly compiled units
 [java]       Ignored 9 units with compilation errors in first pass.
 [java] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
 [java]    [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
 [java] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Failed to get JNode
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:140)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:71)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.getType(BuildTypeMap.java:730)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.access$000(BuildTypeMap.java:99)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap$BuildDeclMapVisitor.visit(BuildTypeMap.java:195)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:237)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ForeachStatement.traverse(ForeachStatement.java:527)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:239)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1239)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:687)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.createPeersForNonTypeDecls(BuildTypeMap.java:637)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.exec(BuildTypeMap.java:514)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.exec(BuildTypeMap.java:523)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:599)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:284)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:233)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
 [java]       [ERROR] <no source info>: public final enum com.dashboard.enums.DaysOfWeekEnum
 [java]     extends Enum<com.dashboard.enums.DaysOfWeekEnum>
 [java] /*   fields   */
 [java] public static final [unresolved] com.dashboard.enums.DaysOfWeekEnum Monday
 [java] public static final [unresolved] com.dashboard.enums.DaysOfWeekEnum Tuesday
 [java] public static final [unresolved] com.dashboard.enums.DaysOfWeekEnums Wednesday
 [java] public static final [unresolved] com.dashboard.enums.DaysOfWeekEnum Thursday
 [java] public static final [unresolved] com.dashboard.enums.DaysOfWeekEnum Friday
 [java] public static final [unresolved] com.dashboard.enums.DaysOfWeekEnum Saturday
 [java] public static final [unresolved] com.dashboard.enums.DaysOfWeekEnum Sunday
    com.dashboard.enums.DaysOfWeekEnum[] $VALUES
         [java] /*   methods   */
         [java] [unresolved] private void <init>() 
         [java] [unresolved] public static com.dashboard.enums.DaysOfWeekEnum valueOf(java.lang.String) 
         [java] [unresolved] public static com.dashboard.enums.DaysOfWeekEnum[] values() 
         [java]          org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding
         [java]       [ERROR] at FormPanel.java(104): com.dashboard.enums.DaysOfWeekEnum day;
         [java]          org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration
```

Comment: There is a workaround given in the link you have provided: _...by declaring "Status.values()[0].toString();" in the "onModuleLoad()" code. We
fixed the problem_. Just replace `Status` with `DaysOfWeekEnum`.

Comment: Of course there is the other fix - use a more recent version of GWT. To my knowledge at least, that ancient version of GXT will still work with a newer version of GWT, but you'd need to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed by adding the Enum class package under source path="" in gwt.xml.

```
<source path='myapplication/enums/'/>
```